# In WatchOS3 Sirikit Payment validation not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, watchkit, apple-watch, watch

I am working on WatchOS3 for Sirikit payment intent. 
First time payee and amount validation is working properly. Once transaction completed . If I am doing transaction, it restore previous payee name and amount means If I am saying "Transfer" it should ask for payee and amount, instead it uses payee name and amount.

In between If I am using different command and try to transfer once again then it behave correctly means proper validation happening.

Any idea why Siri behaves like this for apple watch? Same code is working fine for iPhone.